# How to use services section of manifest during Eclipse-Bluemix Liberty for Java deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud-tools

I have a manifest.yml for a sample java application.  It includes the database service in it:
applications:
- name: redbooklibrary
  memory: 512M
  path: RedbookLibrary.war
  host: redbook-library-rew-eclipse3
  buildpack: liberty-for-java 
services:
 - library_db

I have library_db already created in Bluemix (SQLDB).  When I push this application through the command line, the SQLDB library_db service is automatically bound and the application works fine.

When I deploy the same application through Eclipse, I have to go through the whole deployment wizard, and manually check the library_db service.  I can change the host name in the manifest, and the wizard is picking up the new name, so it is finding the manifest.  However, if I deploy without manually selecting library_db, the service is not bound.  So, it looks like it ignores the services section of the manifest.  If I select the service manually, the application binds and works just fine.

I there something else I need to do to get Eclipse->Bluemix to recognize the services section of the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a manifest.yml in your Web Project in Eclipse Tools for Bluemix, and that manifest.yml includes a named service instance which already exists in your space, then the wizard *should* automatically pick that up when you go to deploy the application.

This means, in your case, the library_db service should be automatically checked on the services page of the wizard (but in your case, it sounds like it isn't, which would be bug.)

However, I've tried to reproduce this problem in the latest version of IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix (as of August 2015 is v1.0.4), and this scenario works as expected: when I go to deploy an application with a manifest.yml, I see the service checkbox is automatically checked, based on the service value in the manifest.yml.

My suggestion is to use the "Save to manifest file" check box on the first page of the deployment wizard. This will save a manifest.yml file for your project, and you can compare this with the manifest.yml you are currently using (as posted in your question description).

Comment: I upgraded the tools, and I'm still seeing the same behavior.  I also did a fresh install - same problem.  Glad its working for you.  I've asked a couple of other folks to see if its working for them, and I'm just the odd one out.  Will let you know.

Comment: Good news.   Jonathan figured out the difference why mine wasn't working.  The alignment of my services entry in the manifest was not indented properly.  cf command line still worked, but not Eclipse.  Once I indented the services entry so it aligns directly below buildpack, Eclipse works correctly too.

Comment: In an effort to reproduce this issue, please provide a copy of your manifest.yml in its failing state.  Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure the service as bound to the application in its configuration on Bluemix UI or using CF client.
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/reqnsi.html#req_instance

If not bound, opening on Eclipse you see a configuration like the one found in the screenshot[image]

The service is not bound to the application on Bluemix, so everytime I deploy the app to Bluemix I have to add it manually if I want to bind it to the application.